# install-pkg command in not working in repl.it

Tags: bash, replit

Here is my code:

```
install-pkg "Minecraft.deb"
```

I am trying to install a .deb package and whenever I run the code, I get an error message telling me that they could not find the install-pkg command.

I cannot find out how to do it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `dpkg -i Minecraft.deb`

Comment: I cannot use sudo command